# $_session in a Datetime NOW( )

Tags: php, date, session

I don't know how to create a $_SESSION with this :

```
    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO pro(reference, date_add) VALUES ( :reference, NOW() ) '); 
    $query->execute(array(
        ':reference' => $_POST['reference']
        ));

    $_SESSION['reference'] = $_POST['reference'];
    $_SESSION['date_add'] = ?
```

My date isn't post before, so how to create a session for my date ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I doesn't understand well what do you want. To store the date simple do: $_SESSION['date_add'] = date();

Comment: use date('Y-m-d H:i:s') or see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You want to put in your session the timestamp generated by NOW in your SQL command ? Because if you put date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), it will not be exactly the same.

Comment: @ThibaultM Actually it will give you exactly the same.

Comment: @Daan If you use NOW() in SQL and after time() in PHP and if you're SQL command take some time, it will not. It can be, but it's not sure. But your respond below is the best way.

Comment: @ThibaultM I meant it is the same result NOW() and date(). Not the actual values when inserting.

Comment: @Daan I agree then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the same result:

```
    //MySQL datetime format (same as NOW())
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO pro(reference, date_add) VALUES ( :reference, :date ) '); 
    $query->execute(array(
        ':reference' => $_POST['reference'],
        ':date' => $date
        ));

    $_SESSION['reference'] = $_POST['reference'];
    $_SESSION['date_add'] = $date
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe can work this

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO pro(reference, date_add) VALUES ( :reference, :date_add ) '); 
    $query->execute(array(
        ':reference' => $_POST['reference'],
        ':date_add' => time()
        ));

    $_SESSION['reference'] = $_POST['reference'];
    $_SESSION['date_add'] = time();
```